# Watch and mutation in vuejs/vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, mutation

So I managed to get to `watch` an element from `state` but I want also to update an element from state.

This is what I tried but it doesn't seam to  work:

```
<template>
  <input :style="styleForX" ... />
</template>


// script in template file :: isXActive returns focus input = true/false
 watch: {
  isXActive: (isXActive) => {
    console.log(123);
    this.$store.commit("SET_STYLE_FOR_X", isXActive);
  },
},
computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    "styleForX",
]);


// state.js
export default state = {styleForX: ""}

// getters.js
styleForX: (state) => {
  return state.styleForX;
},

// action.js
SET_STYLE_FOR_X({commit}, isXActive) {
  const style = isXActive? {backgroundColor: "white", zIndex: "51"} : "";
  commit("SET_STYLE_FOR_X", style);
},


// mutation.js
SET_STYLE_FOR_X(state, styleForX) {
  state.styleForX= styleForX;
}
```

Every js file has the `export default` statement.
Any idea how should I make it work?

1. Update:

Changed code to:

```
 watch: {
  isXActive: () => {
    this.$store.commit("SET_STYLE_FOR_X", {backgroundColor: "white", zIndex: "51"});
  },
```

but still doesn't work. 
I get `this` as `undefined`, so I get this error:

```
Error in callback for watcher "isXActive": "TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined" found in ...
```

2. Update - I changed it to this and this works. But still if anyone knows how to make the first version work please drop a comment. Thank you!

```
created() {
  this.$store.watch(
    () => this.$store.state.isXActive,
    () => {
      this.$store.commit("SET_STYLE_FOR_X", {backgroundColor: "white", zIndex: "51"});
    }
  );
}
```

3. Update - because the style was not remove on focus out I changed it again to:

```
created() {
  this.$store.watch(
    () => this.$store.state.isXActive,
    () => {
      this.$store.dispatch("SET_STYLE_FOR_X", isXActive);
    }
  );
}

// action.js
SET_STYLE_FOR_X({commit}, isXActive) {
  const style = isXActive? {backgroundColor: "white", zIndex: "51"} : "";
  commit("SET_STYLE_FOR_X", style);
},
```

4. Update - end result

```
 watch: {
  isXActive() {
    this.$store.commit("SET_STYLE_FOR_X", this.$store.state.isXActive);
  },
```

Thank you eli chen !!

Comment: i fixed my answer. dont use arrow function in the watcher if you need access to `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your watch handler, you are calling `this.$store.commit` when it appears you intend to call `this.$store.dispatch()`. `commit` runs a mutation. `dispatch` runs an action. Your code for calculating the style from the boolean value is in the action, therefore you should use `dispatch`.

That said, there is no reason to use an action here since you don't have any asynchronous code. Simply put the logic for the style string inside the mutation instead of in the action.

Answer (score 3):

you code is invalid. the `isXActive` inside the watcher is **boolean type** (like you said in the comment above it) and `styleForX` from the store is **style object type** for style the input. now when watcher got trigged you send a boolean type to the mutation and the mutation set the styleForX to boolean type.

you should send a style string not a boolean for example

```
watch: {
  isXActive: function() {
    this.$store.commit("SET_STYLE_FOR_X", {backgroundColor: "white", zIndex: "51"});
  }
}
```

example of object style type is `{ color: 'red' }`. this is just js object take a look here for more info https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Binding-Inline-Styles